# Add constraint to SQL Server with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    employee_number INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    employee_name NVARCHAR(100), 
    employee_year INT,
    manager_employee_number INT, 
    salary INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(manager_employee_number) 
         REFERENCES employee(employee_number)
);
```

I want to add a constraint which every employee's `employee_year` is less than his manager's and we know every manager is an employee himself. So I wrote this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeYearLessThanManager
        CHECK (employee_year <= (SELECT m.employee_year 
                                 FROM employee 
                                 WHERE m.employee_number = manager_employee_number ));
```

I get this error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Is there any possible way to write such a constraint?

Comment: No, as the error states you can't do that. You could use a **set-based** `TRIGGER` to enforce the logic.

Comment: Though, I must admit, logically this doesn't make sense. A manager can be hired after one of their employees (assuming `employee_year` represents years of service).

Comment: @larnu tnx. about the next comment, it's the assumption of the database that every employee must be hired after a manager.

Comment: That's a *bad* assumption, because it's not true. Otherwise I need to talk to my employer and get them to reemploy about 80% of the company as we hired a new Director at the end of the year.

Comment: @Larnu That's not my call. Maybe there's some justice attitude that a manager must be chosen from employees and shouldn't be a new employee.

Comment: Then speak to whomever's call it is and explain to them that the design is wrong... I've had multiple managers that have been hired *after* me, or where someone who was hired *after* me has applied for a managerial role that I did not apply for. This call sounds like its come from someone who doesn't understand data and thus it is your job, as someone who does, to explain why that design is flawed.

Comment: @Larnu, Ok. I would consider it and tell them.

Comment: @Larnu This could be a cultural issue, where longevity of service is a prerequisite for promotion. I have certainly experienced this. You might consider being a little less forthright in your comments.  What to some cultures seems crazy, is often the norm elsewhere. We do not know the full background.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that actually changes any of my comments, @JonathanWillcock .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it can be seen from the error message, you cannot implement it as a subquery, but as a work around you can create a scalar-valued user defined function and call it from the check constraint. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    employee_number INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    employee_name NVARCHAR(100), 
    employee_year INT,
    manager_employee_number INT, 
    salary INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(manager_employee_number) 
         REFERENCES employee(employee_number)
);
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_manager_hire_year(@manager_employee_number INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @e_year int;
   SELECT @e_year = employee_year
   FROM employee 
   WHERE employee_number = @manager_employee_number;

   RETURN @e_year
END
GO

ALTER TABLE employee 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_EmployeeYearLessThanManager
        CHECK (employee_year <= dbo.get_manager_hire_year(manager_employee_number))
```

Comment: This type of logic in check constraints does not work well. If the manager's `employee_year` is updated downwards to violate the constraint then it won't fire on the sub ordinate rows which are now invalid. Even in cases where the constraint does fire you can still get invalid data - e.g. if it is reading old data due to snapshot isolation being in use or (because it is evaluated row by row) because the order of updates is in the "wrong" order for it in the event of a multirow update